# Unable to select dropdown inside iframe using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, iframe, dropdown

I am unable to select any value from dropdown which lies inside iframe of the following url: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/button-dropdown-select

Following is my code:

```
public class SelectDropdown {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver_2.33\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver();
    chrome.get("https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/button-dropdown-select");

    chrome.switchTo().frame("snippet-preview");
    System.out.println("frame passed");

    WebElement dropDownLocation = chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class = 'selectpicker'][5]"));
    System.out.println("dropdown found");

    Select abc = new Select(dropDownLocation);
    System.out.println("dropdownLocation found");

    abc.selectByVisibleText("Relish");
    System.out.println("dropdown value selected");

}

}
```

And following is the exception that I am getting:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible:
>   Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two matching `WebElement` to that `xpath`, the dropdown you are looking for and a child element of the dropdown sibling under `bs-docs-example` class. You try to locate an element without that class.

```
WebElement dropDownLocation = chrome.findElement(By.xpath("//*[not(@class='bs-docs-example')]/select[@class = 'selectpicker'][5]"));
```